# Highcharts: How to remove tiny space between stacked bars/columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I have a [simple stacked column chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/).

```
            plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

I want to remove the tiny bit of space between the stacked columns. Is there a way to do it.
Here is an image to better explain the space I wish to remove: [image]

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the outputted html. If these blocks are `inline-block` level elements, this could be a whitespace issue. If not are the margin/padding on them? Are there `<br>` tags?

Comment: I hyperlinked to a jsfiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the [border width](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.borderWidth) to 0:

```
plotOptions: {
            column: {
               borderWidth: 0,
...
}
```